# Intellij IDEA error - Could not autowire. No beans of 'HttpSecurity' type found

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-security

I was trying out the following example in

https://github.com/lspil/blog/tree/master/endpoint-authorization-methods/spring-security-endpoint-authorization-new

and it works fine without any errors in Intellij IDEA. But as soon as I change the Spring Boot version from **2.4.4** to **2.7.1** in **pom.xml**, it throws an IDE error:

**Could not autowire. No beans of 'HttpSecurity' type found**  for the following:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configuration(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  ..........................
```

The application works fine but would be interested to know why this is happening. Version of IDE is IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Do you have "Spring Batch" plugin installed?

Comment: You can get rid of the error by adding `@EnableWebSecurity` to your configuration class. I am talking to the Spring Security team if there is a way to solve this problem

Comment: @y.bedrov No I don't have "Spring Batch" plugin installed

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Yes, adding `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation removes the error. Funny thing is that the error doesn't come back even if we remove the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation.....very strange!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For some reason, the IDE cannot detect that the [`HttpSecurity` bean is configured by Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ac59b5781f30d98b8873fd0dc0010a5dbb9ccf5b/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.java#L99-L105). You can get rid of the error by adding `@EnableWebSecurity` to your configuration class, it solves it because the annotation imports the `HttpSecurityConfiguration` configuration class.

The IntelliJ team has fixed this problem, you can get more information about the fix and which version it is available [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289633/Spring-Boot-new-auto-configuration-registration-in-v-27).

Available in IntelliJ   2022.2 EAP 3, 2022.1.3

Comment: I have both @EnableWebSecurity annotation and installed IntellijJ version 2022.3.3 and still get the Intellij error.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason of the issue except IDE problem is about versions of Spring Boot and Spring Security. Their versions should be compatible with each other.

If your spring boot project version is around `2.2.x`, you should use spring security `5.x` but If your spring boot project version is around `3.1.x`, you should use spring security `6.x`.

Reference: [Error: Could not autowire. No beans of type 'httpSecurity' found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76831213/error-could-not-autowire-no-beans-of-type-httpsecurity-found)

Author: M. Deinum