# Error: Could not autowire. No beans of type 'httpSecurity' found

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a spring security configuration class in order to further use jwt for validation. However, when doing basic configurations I stumbled upon this issue, where the HttpSecurity bean I'm using as a parameter for a SecurityFilterChain is not recognized, thus resulting in an error when my container is running.

I already tried using the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter even though its supposed to be deprecated. I have also tried the default usage provided in spring documentation.I also tried to declare it manually since I had the same issue with AuthenticationManager but with a latter declaration this was fixed. That being the case, could it be possible to manually declare httpSecurity? This is my code(I am using IntellijIDEA):

```
package com.company.project.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http(THIS IS WHERE THE BEAN IS NOT FOUND), AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception{
    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .build();
    }
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>New App</name>
    <description>My new SpringBoot app</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Show your dependencies and tell which Spring Boot / Spring Security version you are using.

Comment: Done. I am unsure if its okay for me to use the latest versions of spring security with previous versions of java/spring boot.

Comment: You are mixing Spring Boot versions (2.2.x and lATEST) that isn't going to work. You need to use the same version. Using the latest Spring Security version with Spring Boot 2.2. will not work. Simply due to the fact that it requires Spring 6, whereas Spring Boot 2.2. is still on Spring 5.x).